# Automatically replace the PlantUML code in an .adoc file with the corresponding PNG images

Tags: automation, markdown, asciidoc, code-documentation, plantuml

I have a big .adoc file with plantUML Diagrams in it. The main goal is to convert the .adoc from asciidoc to markdown. For that it is necessary to replace the .puml diagrams to images (png). Its possible to extract the .PNGs from a .adoc file, but so far I did not figure out if there maybe is a tool, library etc. that could replace the .puml diagrams with the corresponding PNG version of it.

Does someone a solution for this? I guess the really last approach would be to write a bashscript that does that automatically (sed commands), but I would love not to do that.

Would be grateful for Answers, have a nice day!

Comment: What's the end goal? Where will the markdown be used? Pandoc has filters to support plantuml diagrams inside markdown (diagram-generator) if you're using the markdown to produce html or pdf, for example.

Comment: Here's the link to https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/tree/master/diagram-generator (see the readme).

Comment: @Fuhrmanator : The endgoal is a github workflow that replaces the puml diagrams in a reduced .adoc file with the corresponding .png images. Then it can properly be converted into markdown and used as a documentation.

Comment: with pandoc we had trouble with tables not being converted correctly

Comment: I use Quarto.org for generating documentation (HTML, PDF) in a GitHub workflow, including the filter for PlantUML. Have a look at https://github.com/fuhrmanator/log210-ndc-quarto/blob/main/.github/workflows/quarto-render-publish.yml -- the source markdown files are `.qmd` (Quarto) which uses Pandoc under the hood. Here's the support for table formats: https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/tables.html. I like that PlantUML can be stored in the markdown, so no separate files to manage. It can generate PNG or SVG for documentation. SVG is searchable (PNG is not).

Comment: It's unfortunate that pandoc can't read asciidoc format (it can only write to it, at least according to https://pandoc.org/). Maybe convert from Asciidoc -> DocBook -> markdown (Pandoc imports from DocBook)?

Comment: https://tinyapps.org/blog/201701240700_convert_asciidoc_to_markdown.html and https://alvinalexander.com/bookmarks/how-convert-asciidoc-to-html-or-markdown/ explain the same asciidoc -> markdown pipeline. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator Thanks, I will try out the alternatives!

Comment: @Fuhrmanator Tried out the asciidoc -> markdown pipeline from your last two links. Sadly, plantuml won't render as a diagram

Comment: Does the PlantUML source show up in the markdown? If so, the `diagram-generator` filter has to be used in your pipeline. Your question really needs a minimal example of how you're using PlantUML in asciidoc.

Comment: So if I use your recommended pipeline and convert it to markdown, the result is:

mytext..... with Puml:
`@startuml ... @enduml`

so it displays / renders as the codeblock in the markdown.

before the conversion in the reduced .adoc its used like this:

[plantuml, target=<nameofumlfile>, format=svg]
...
@startuml
...
@enduml

This gets rendered as diagram, but as mentioned, its in .adoc

Comment: I will try out the diagram generator as the next step

Comment: @Fuhrmanator: I tried out the following process: convert reduced .adoc to xml with docbook and then with pandoc to markdown. The result is a markdown where the puml diagrams are still in code. Then I tried out the diagram generator on in with the lua filter that should generate puml with the code thats inside the .md - sadly, same result and nothing was changed...

Comment: If you don't post samples of what you're trying in the question, it's difficult/impossible to help.

Comment: Install pandoc and asciidoc

`sudo apt install pandoc asciidoc`

Convert asciidoc to docbook

`asciidoc -b docbook foo.adoc`

Convert docbook to markdown

`pandoc -f docbook -t markdown_strict foo.xml -o foo.md`
THEN diagram generator:
`pandoc foo.md -f markdown --to=markdown --embed-resources --standalone --lua-filter=diagram-generator.lua 
--metadata=plantumPath:"C:\Users\me\project\docs\src\diagram-generator\plantuml-1.2023.1.jar" 
--metadata=javaPath:"C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_362\bin\java.exe" -o formatted_foo.md`

Result as if nothing happened

Comment: @Fuhrmanator I hope the last comment can help

Comment: Please edit your question and put the example of `foo.adoc` in the question (not comments).

Comment: Hey, thank you very much and sorry for the little detail I provided. In meantime I created some scripts that take the reduced asciidocs and execute plantUML with its jar to export all plantuml to png. After that a second script runs through the asciidocs to delete all plantUML diagrams and replaces them with the coressponding png.

Answer (score 0):

If you convert the PlantUML to PNG, you cannot maintain the diagrams anymore. I assume you want to keep the documents up-to-date and use Markdown as the source of truth.

You can keep PlantUML inside Markdown, similarly to what you do in AsciiDoc. The only extra that you have to use a preprocessor:

https://github.com/verhas/jamal

If you use IntelliJ, you can edit the Markdown text with macros, including the PlantUML text, and see the formatted text with the diagram in WYSIWYG on the right pane. You will have the XXX.md.jam and the XXX.md automatically saved simultaneously using the Asciidoctor plugin and the Jamal preprocessor with it.

I created Jamal. It is open-source. If you need any more help, you can reach me.

It may not be the answer you are looking for, but may also be.

Comment: Hey, Thank you very much for your suggestion. I created some scripts that take the reduced asciidocs and execute plantUML with its jar to export all plantuml to png. After that a second script runs through the asciidocs to delete all plantUML diagrams and replaces them with the coressponding png